# Error when compiling code with the Protege API

Tags: java, owl, protege

I am new to Protege API and I have just created on Eclipse a small application which uses an external OWL file. Also I did import all the necessary libraries.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import edu.stanford.smi.protege.exception.OntologyLoadException;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL;
import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.*;

public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws OntologyLoadException {
        String uri = "C:/Documents and Settings/Anto/Desktop/travel.owl";
        OWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(uri);
        Collection classes = owlModel.getUserDefinedOWLNamedClasses();

        for (Iterator it = classes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            OWLNamedClass cls = (OWLNamedClass) it.next();
            Collection instances = cls.getInstances(false);
            System.out.println("Class " + cls.getBrowserText() + " ("
                    + instances.size() + ")");

            for (Iterator jt = instances.iterator(); jt.hasNext();) {
                OWLIndividual individual = (OWLIndividual) jt.next();
                System.out.println(" - " + individual.getBrowserText());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I do compile however I get the following errors:

```
WARNING: [Local Folder Repository] The specified file must be a directory.      
(C:\Documents and Settings\Anto\My Documents\Eclipse 
Workspace\ProtegeTrial\plugins\edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl) 
LocalFolderRepository.update()
SEVERE: Exception caught -- java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at 
index 12: C:/Documents and Settings/CiuffreA/Desktop/travel.owl
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.getFileURI(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.loadKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.loadDomainKB(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.creator.OwlProjectFromUriCreator.create(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(Unknown Source)
at Trial.main(Trial.java:14)


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.loadKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.loadDomainKB(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.creator.OwlProjectFromUriCreator.create(Unknown Source)
at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI(Unknown Source)
at Trial.main(Trial.java:14)
```

Does anyone have an idea on where the problem should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
String uri = "C:/Documents and Settings/Anto/Desktop/travel.owl";
```

with

```
String uri = "file:///C:/Documents and Settings/Anto/Desktop/travel.owl";
```